# What is the default value for logLevel?

Tags: .net, azure, diagnostics

I'm using System.Diagnostics on my Azure instances. I have some settings on my webconfig:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <!-- Off = 0, Error 1, Warning = 2, Info = 3, Verbose = 4 -->
      <add name="logLevel" value="2" />
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true"
     ...
```

I would like to know what is the default logLevel value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default value for switch. `value` is required attribute. Application will throw ConfigurationErrorsException if no value is provided (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.switch.value.aspx)).

Read more about configuration [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cex3872f.aspx).